# Trigger JSF ajax form programmatically via JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, jsf-2

My goal is to call a JSF managed bean method from inside a JS function.

This is the function:

```
var fbLogin = function() {
                FB.login( 
                    function(response) {
                        if (response.authResponse) {
                            var access_token =   FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
                            console.log(access_token);
                            //document.getElementById("hiddenFbForm:hiddenFbToken").value = access_token;
                            //document.getElementById("hiddenFbForm:hiddenFbLoginSubmit").onclick();
                        } else {
                            console.log("ERROR");
                        }
                    }, 
                    {scope:'email'}
                );
            };
```

My idea was having a hidden JSF ajax form, filling a hidden field and triggering click on submit commandlink:

```
<h:form id="hiddenFbForm">
            <h:inputHidden id="hiddenFbToken" value="#{loginController.fbToken}" />
            <h:commandLink id="hiddenFbLoginSubmit" actionListener="#{loginController.printFbInfo()}" />
        </h:form>
```

However, this doesn't work. Page reloads, my *printFbInfo* server side method is never reached.

Do you have better ideas for calling a JSF server side bean from a JS function (programmatically, I don't want my user to click a button).

Another thing... I want the call to be AJAX, not reloading the page.

Comment: Are you willing to use Primefaces??

Comment: Why don't you use direct action like following: `<h:commandLink id="hiddenFbLoginSubmit" action="#{loginController.printFbInfo}" />`

Comment: Yes I'm using Primefaces too. I wrote I don't want a direct action because 1) I don't want a user click but a programmatic click 2) I want an ajax call to my server method, no page reload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Removing Braces from Action listener method
instead of `#{loginController.printFbInfo()}` use `#{loginController.printFbInfo}`.

Since you are using Primefaces you could use [Primefaces RemoteCommand](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/remoteCommand.jsf) (`p:remoteCommand`) to achieve this.

Comment: Primefaces remote command was the way to go. Thank you. I wonder how this could be done without Primefaces however. :)